# No such table when in fact there is. sqlite3 in c

Tags: sql, c, database, sqlite

```
  char *sql = "SELECT * FROM links;";
  rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, 0, &error);
  printf("%s\n", error);
```

I'm getting *no such table: links* as output from this code, but when I try the same query 'manually' on [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) seems to work. If I try to pass only one argument at a time like

```
char *sql = "SELECT id FROM links;";
```

nothing change.

Comment: Maybe you are using two different database files?

Comment: Try to remove `;` at the end. Also you can find available tables via `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'` and copy the name.

Comment: @astentx: If it insists on having the `;` removed that'd be a bug in sqlite; the standard is for the `;` to be there.

Comment: Did you run into case sensitivity problems?

Comment: @astentx no, if I copy and paste the query in DB Browser the query runs perfectly

Comment: @mkrieger1 I only have one database and one table (that is links)